# Change settings in the prediction model (caret package)

Tags: r, predictive-models, caret, boosting

I am using the package `caret` and GBM method for my predictions.

```
fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
        method = "repeatedcv",
        number = 10,
        ## repeated ten times
        repeats = 10)

gbmGrid <-  expand.grid(interaction.depth = c(1, 5, 9),
                        n.trees = (1:30)*50,
                        shrinkage = 0.1)

gbmFit <- train(target ~ ., data = traindf,
                method = "gbm",
                trControl = fitControl,
                verbose = FALSE,
                ## Now specify the exact models 
                ## to evaludate:
                tuneGrid = gbmGrid,
                metric = "ROC")
```

There is one concept that I misunderstand. User guides of `caret` say that "**By default, the train function chooses the model with the largest performance value (or smallest, for mean squared error in regression models).**" So, when I run `ggplot(gbmFit)` I get this graphic:

[image]

When I type `gbmFit` in the console, I see that "**The final values used for the model were n.trees = 300, interaction.depth = 9 and shrinkage = 0.1**"  How can I manually change these settings in order to make my predictions with different number of boosting iterations and trees?:

```
predictions_gbm <- predict(gbmFit, newdata = testdf, type = "raw")
```

Answer (score 1):

See `?update.train`. For example:

```
new_mod <- update(gbmFit, list(n.trees = 100, 
                               interaction.depth = 1,
                               shrinkage = 0.1))
```

Comment: Can you add some text relating this to the OP's question / explaining how this resolves the issue? I suspect you're right, but it might be nice to have a little more.